# is there a way to efficiently fill a pandas df column in python with hourly datetimes between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

So I am looking for a way to fill an empty dataframe column with hourly values between two dates.
for example between

> StartDate = 2019:01:01 00:00:00

to

> EndDate = 2019:02:01 00:00:00

I would want a column that has

> 2019:01:01 00:00:00,2019:01:01 01:00:00,2019:02:01 00:00:00...

in Y:M:D H:M:S format.
I am not sure what the most efficient way of doing this is, is there a way to do it via pandas or would you have to use a for loop over a given timedelta between a range for eg?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
StartDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
EndDate = '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(StartDate, EndDate, freq='H')})
```

If there is custom format of dates first convert them to datetimes:

```
StartDate = '2019:01:01 00:00:00'
EndDate = '2019:02:01 00:00:00'

StartDate = pd.to_datetime(StartDate, format='%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
EndDate = pd.to_datetime(EndDate, format='%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(StartDate, EndDate, freq='H')})
print (df.head(10))
                dates
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00
1 2019-01-01 01:00:00
2 2019-01-01 02:00:00
3 2019-01-01 03:00:00
4 2019-01-01 04:00:00
5 2019-01-01 05:00:00
6 2019-01-01 06:00:00
7 2019-01-01 07:00:00
8 2019-01-01 08:00:00
9 2019-01-01 09:00:00
```